# Cannot inject an Angular ngModel in directive in Kendo Grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

I am trying to add an input directive in order to trim all text inputs. So far this is the code of my directive:

```
app.directive("input", function directive() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    priority: 1,
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      element.on("focusout", function triggerChange(event) {
        var input = event.target;
        if (input.value && input.type === "text") {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(input.value.trim());
          ctrl.$render();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

My issue is that the ngModel does not seem to be injected, as I get the error:
`Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'input', can't be found!`

Any idea why this happens, and how to fix it?

Update:

Actually, this is the interaction of Kendo Grid and AngularJS. The input I am testing is generated by Kendo Grid. The code of the column is standard:

```
{ field: "name", title: "titleName" }
```

Comment: Why you call your directive `input`? Why you don't choose custom name? Like `myInput`? This can cause some conflicts

Comment: Hey man show us code how you used this directive in the HTML. I am sure you have not provided ng-model  in the directive element It should be something like <my-directive ng-model="something"> </my-directive> in you case <input ng-model="something"> </input>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is not perfect, but it is the best I could find:

```
app.directive("input", function directive() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    priority: 1,
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      element.on("focusout", function triggerChange(event) {
        var input = $(event.target);
        input.val(input.val().trim());
        input.trigger("change");
      });
    }
  };
});
```

So basically, we trim the input, and use `input.trigger("change")` to inform the system that the input has changed.

A warning though, it does not work with our validation system (valdr).

Answer (score 0):

You must have some `input` element in your HTML which does not have `ng-model`.

You can change your code to `require: "?ngModel",` and later check if `ctrl` is `undefined` or not, like:

```
app.directive("input", function directive() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    priority: 1,
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) { return ;}
      element.on("focusout", function triggerChange(event) {
        var input = event.target;
        if (input.value && input.type === "text") {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(input.value.trim());
          ctrl.$render();
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have provided `ng-model` in your html when you use this directive because you wrote  `require: 'ngModel',` in the directive. so in your case your directive name is input so it will be something like

```
<input ng-model="something"> </input>
```